# Whats wrong with this function? .each related

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I uncomment the alert the data is there... like:

```
{ 
      'Huishoudelijke hulp': 'Huishoudelijke hulp', 
      'Verpleging thuis': 'Verpleging thuis',
      'Verzorging thuis': 'Verzorging thuis',
      '24 uurs zorg': '24 uurs zorg',
      'Ondersteunende begeleiding': 'Ondersteunende begeleiding',
    }
```

But instead of populating the key and the value it takes the whole var and start to create a key and value pair for each character.

You can see this in action here:
http://www.zorgzuster-zeeland.nl/site/static/calendar_test.php

create a task in the calendar and then try to edit the task by clicking on it.
It should populate the dropdown field properly.

When i create a static var with the same values the dropdown works.

static variable

```
var zvmlist = { 
      'Huishoudelijke hulp': 'Huishoudelijke hulp', 
      'Verpleging thuis': 'Verpleging thuis',
      'Verzorging thuis': 'Verzorging thuis',
      '24 uurs zorg': '24 uurs zorg',
      'Ondersteunende begeleiding': 'Ondersteunende begeleiding',
    };
```

This is my function, anybody has a clue?

```
$.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(zvmlist) {
        //alert("Data Loaded: " + zvmlist);

            $.each(zvmlist, function(key, value) { 
              var selected='';
              if(key==eventdata.title){var selected='selected' }
              $('<option value="'+key+'" '+selected+'>'+value+'</option>').appendTo($('#calendar_edit_entry_form_title')); 

            }); 

        });
```

Comment: I dont think that `jquery` and `mysql` tags can coesist in the same question.

Comment: thats the current key saved in a session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    "url":"get_zorgvormen.php",
    "dataType":"json",
    "type":"get",
    "success":function(zvmlist){
        // should alert [Object object] or something similar
        alert(zvmlist);
    },
    "error":function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: id does alert Object object, how doe i pass de zvmlist to my each function then?

Comment: it is maybe obvious for intermediate jquery guys, but i am a newbie in jquery

Comment: clicking the V i presume? did it.

Answer (score 2):

Your server responds with `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `application/json`, so jQuery doesn't eval your object. You could specify the content type:

```
$.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(zvmlist) {
    $.each(zvmlist, function(key, value) { 
        var selected = '';
        if(key==eventdata.title) { 
            selected = 'selected';
        }
        $('<option value="'+key+'" '+selected+'>'+value+'</option>')
            .appendTo($('#calendar_edit_entry_form_title')); 
   }); 
}, 'json');
```

But I would recommend you to fix your [server side script](http://www.zorgzuster-zeeland.nl/site/static/get_zorgvormen.php) to send the correct content-type and jquery will automatically recognize the `json` format and eval the response of the server.

Comment: i added the proper headers but still no luck

<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit");



$query = "SELECT id,zorgvormen_Naam FROM zorgvormen WHERE parent_zorgvormen_id=0";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "{";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "'". $row['zorgvormen_Naam']. "':'". $row['zorgvormen_Naam']. "',";
 
}
echo "}";


?>

Comment: Your initial test link no longer makes an ajax call to this script.

Comment: i added . json at the end of my function. so i removed it again.

Answer (score 0):

You dont tell Jquery to expect a json format.

From the documentation:

```
jQuery.get( url, [ data ], [ callback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], [ dataType ] )

urlA string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

dataA map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

callback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

dataTypeThe type of data expected from the server.
```

[source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Try to specify that you expect Json:

```
$.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(zvmlist) {
        //alert("Data Loaded: " + zvmlist);

            $.each(zvmlist, function(key, value) { 
              var selected='';
              if(key==eventdata.title){var selected='selected' }
              $('<option value="'+key+'" '+selected+'>'+value+'</option>').appendTo($('#calendar_edit_entry_form_title')); 

            }); 

        }, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

David Murdock provided "the trick".
This is how my function looks now, and its working like a charm.

```
$.ajax({
        "url":"get_zorgvormen.php",
        "dataType":"json",
        "type":"get",
        "success":function(zvmlist){

            $.each(zvmlist, function(key, value) { 
              var selected='';
              if(key==eventdata.title){selected='selected' }
              $('<option value="'+key+'" '+selected+'>'+value+'</option>').appendTo($('#calendar_edit_entry_form_title')); 

            });
        },
        "error":function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```